# Error 504, avoid it with some data passing from server to client?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, http-status-code-504

I'm developing an app that should receive a `.CSV` file, save it, scan it, and `insert` data of every record `into DB` and at the end delete the file.

With a file with about 10000 records there aren't problems but with a larger file the `PHP script is correctly runned and all data are saved into DB` but is printed `ERROR 504 The server didn't respond in time.`.

I'm scanning the `.CSV file with the php function fgetcsv();`.

I've already edit settings into `php.ini` file (`max execution time (120)`, etc..) but nothing change, after 1 minute the error is shown.

I've also try to use a javascript function to show an alert every 10 seconds but also in this case the error is shown.

Is there a solution to avoid this problem? Is it possible pass some data from server to client every tot seconds to avoid the error?

Thank's

Comment: 504 is a timeout. You need to extend the allowed execution time in your server settings. However, leaving a connection open that long is a really bad idea for many reasons. I'd suggest you instead let the user upload the file, then do the processing in a background process (ie CRON as you're using PHP/Apache). You can then alert the user either via the UI/email/SMS etc when the processing has finished

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its typically when scaling issues pop up when you need to start evolving your system architecture, and your application will need to work asynchronously.  This problem you are having is very common (some of my team are dealing with one as I write) but everyone needs to deal with it eventually.

Solution 1: Cron Job

The most common solution is to create a cron job that periodically scans a queue for new work to do.  I won't explain the nature of the queue since everyone has their own, some are alright and others are really bad, but typically it involves a DB table with  relevant information and a job status (<-- one of the bad solutions), or a solution involving Memcached, also MongoDB is quite popular.

The "problem" with this solution is ultimately again "scaling".  Cron jobs run periodically at fixed intervals, so if a task takes a particularly long time jobs are likely to overlap.  This means you need to work in some kind of locking or utilize a scheduler that supports running the job sequentially.

In the end, you won't run into the timeout problem, and you can typically dedicate an entire machine to running these tasks so memory isn't as much of an issue either.

Solution 2: Worker Delegation

I'll use Gearman as an example for this solution, but other tools encompass standards like AMQP such as RabbitMQ.  I prefer Gearman because its simpler to set up, and its designed more for work processing over messaging.

This kind of delegation has the advantage of running immediately after you call it.  The server is basically waiting for stuff to do (not unlike an Apache server), when it get a request it shifts the workload from the client onto one of your "workers", these are scripts you've written which run indefinitely listening to the server for workload.

You can have as many of these workers as you like, each running the same or different types of tasks.  This means scaling is determined by the number of workers you have, and this scales horizontally very cleanly.

Conclusion:

Crons are fine in my opinion of automated maintenance, but they run into problems when they need to work concurrently which makes running workers the ideal choice.

Either way, you are going to need to change the way users receive feedback on their requests.  They will need to be informed that their request is processing and to check later to get the result, alternatively you can periodically track the status of the running task to provide real-time feedback to the user via ajax.  Thats a little tricky with cron jobs, since you will need to persist the state of the task during its execution, but Gearman has a nice built-in solution for doing just that.

http://php.net/manual/en/book.gearman.php